# Corda gateway timeout

Tags: blockchain, corda

The standard timeout of gateway is 30seconds. But in some complex flows take more time then this standard. 
How to resolve this issue? 
Does Corda as a platform provide any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually configure your timeout in the node configuration file.

In your `node.conf` file, add this:

```
flowTimeout {
    timeout = 100 seconds
}
```

Then the timeout will be extended to 100 seconds

Here is the reference:
https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/corda-configuration-file.html#referenceconf

Comment: This is a flow timeout, I am talking about gateway timeout. let's consider a scenario where a end user hiting a api , which is calling a flow in corda and that flow complexity is bit high, in that case I might take more then 30sec to give a response back. But standard gateway timeout will happen in 30sec , how to capture that scenario.

Comment: Then I think this is something about the gateway you are using which is outside Corda. Is there any asynchronous approach feasible to you?